# instagram gem JSON::ParserError in SessionController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, instagram-api

I am trying to use the instagram gem to create a gallery of photo from my instagram. I was following this [example](http://blog.ajmalafif.com/instagram-gem-with-rails/) to try to integrate the gem in my app but keep running to this error

> JSON::ParserError in SessionController#index

Any help is well appreciated!

This is my CONTROLLER

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController

def index
 @item = Item.all
 @instagram = ::Instagram.user_recent_media('grateful4salvation', {:count => 2})
 end
end
```

Initializers/instagram.rb

```
require 'instagram'

 Instagram.configure do |config|
 config.client_id = ENV["CLIENT_ID"]
 config.access_token = ENV["access_token"]
 end
```

View/session/index.html

```
<% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
  <%= image_tag instagram.images.standard_resolution.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What about the homeController?

Comment: @manfergo25 sorry about that, the home controller was/is the session controller

Comment: Ok. I think you need to put ENV['CLIENT_ID'] and ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN'] with real values to connect to instagram api. I dont know if you did that.

Comment: yes, its in my .env file

Comment: Try Instagram.user_recent_media([USER_ID]) and in the web check  if you get access => https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[USER_ID_HERE]/follows?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE]

Comment: @manfergo25 do you mean like this " instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media([USER_ID], {:count => 2})
"

Comment: Will serve too. Remember USER_ID is an Integer.

Comment: Got it working! thank! I had to find the user id. got it from http://www.otzberg.net/iguserid/

Answer (score 0):

change

```
@instagram = ::Instagram.user_recent_media('grateful4salvation', {:count => 2})
```

to

```
 @instagram = ::Instagram.user_recent_media( 'user_id', {:count => 2})
```

example:

```
@instagram = ::Instagram.user_recent_media(1368150019, {:count => 2})
```