# JSON::ParserError in HomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I am learning the instagram API, which is complicated by the fact that Instagram just changed their authentication, so there's not a lot of documentation about it yet.

This is basically the same question as [instagram gem JSON::ParserError in SessionController#index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129696/instagram-gem-jsonparsererror-in-sessioncontrollerindex) (I'm even following the same tutorial) but (a) that solution was about the user id - I'm not targeting a user but a general public feed, and (b) it's from before the auth change and I'm pretty sure this is some kind of authentication issue.

Here's my controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @popular = Instagram.media_popular
  end
end
```

Initializers/instagram.rb

```
require "instagram"
   Instagram.configure do |config|
   config.client_id = "MY CLIENT ID"
   config.access_token = "MY ACCESS TOKEN"
end
```

views/home/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Instagram Lookup</h1>
  <% @popular.each do |popular| %>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag popular.images.low_resolution.url %>
      <div class="caption">
        <%= popular.user.username %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
This is Rails 4.2.3, Ruby ruby 2.1.1p76 and Instagram 1.1.6

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have restarted the server after initializing the `client_id` and `access_token` with the correct values?

Also, you need to have a `client` connected to the API (as per official documentation of the gem) and then retreive the `media_popular`through that `client` object.

So something like:

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
@popular = client.media_popular
```

For further reference, click [here](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem)